# Populate second table on click

Tags: php

I've got a table listing all users with their basic information, the last cell of the row is a 'view more', which should populate a second table with detailed information about the user. (see it as 2 panels, left and right, and right one (view more) only displays when view more is clicked).
All the data is stored on the database, I've already succesfully managed to build the first table. But the problem is how to handle the second one, I've build it, and depending a variable it loads content from one user or another, but I don't know how dynamically change that value and load the next user data on the fly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to provide us with your html table, the js you have written so far and possibly you database schema so we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You can't load data on the fly in php. the simple reason is because the [http](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) protocol doesn't work like that.

You basically have 3 diffirent options:
 1. reload the page with another link
 2. Use [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)  to load the data async
 3. Load all the data on the start and hide missing data on page load, and show it when you click more info

Comment: I see, so Iif I got it right, first solution would be displaying all the users on show.php (my current page now), then once I click on the view more, load show.php?id=whatever, is that it?